# when tried to give more than one contact point for APP builder to connect to cassandra seeing ERROR

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Application developer in my team is working on a App builder to connect to cassandra, in properties file I have seen that he is using only one contact point, I have asked him to includes all seed nodes as contact points and changed replication from simplestrategy to NetworkTopologystrategy and code looks like this

```
cassandra.contactPoint=52.xxx.xx.xxx,52.xxx.xx.xxx,10.xxx.xx.xxx,10.xxx.xx.xxx
cassandra.replicationFactor={ 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' :'3' , 'DC2' : '3'}
cassandra.dataCenter=DC1   
cassandra.createKeyspace=false
```

Then we have seen the following error

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   52.xxx.xx.123,52.xxx.xx.125,10.xxx.xx.xxx,10.xxx.xx.xxx    com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.addContactPoint(Cluster.java:749)

So I asked him to include seed nodes present in DC1 then we restarted and saw this error

> Session ERROR  - Error creating pool to /52.xxx.xx.125:9042   Caused
>   by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /52.xxx.xx.125:9042

I have few questions on this

1. What does `cassandra.datacenter()` do? Do we need to specify contact points present in that particular DC? If so what should I add to that if I need to include my seed nodes involving both DC's?
2. Even after specifying nodes belonging to that particular DC we got errors. Is this because of replication factor we have mentioned? Is the syntax of it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to the cluster has nothing to do with the replication factor. When connecting to a cluster you usually want to have enough node IP addresses specified so that you are sure at least one of them is up when your app tries to connect. Regarding seed nodes the rule of a thumb is to have 1 seed node per every 3 nodes in the cluster (this changes based on deployment but not too much).
As for first exception, make sure you are providing a node list parameter to drivers method addContactPoints which accepts a list of Strings. The second error looks like the port you specified is closed or you defined some other port in cassandra.yaml
Drivers gets the topology of the cluster when you connect to the first node so this list doesnt define which datacenter it will connect to. Datacenter isolation is forced with consistency levels on statement.